# Get information from an array/object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
{
  brandBrandId: {
    brandId: 2,
    brandName: "Hikka",
    isGun: true
  },
  modelId: "1",
  modelName: "Hikka model"
}, {
  brandBrandId: {
    brandId: 3,
    brandName: "Bebrand",
    isGun: true
  },
  modelId: "2",
  modelName: "Bebrand model 1"
}, {
  brandBrandId: {
    brandId: 2,
    brandName: "Hikka",
    isGun: true
  },
  modelId: "3",
  modelName: "Hikka model2"
}
```

**javascript**

```
var models = $scope.models;
console.log("selectedBrand---->" + selectedBrand);
    for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
    console.log(i+" : " +[i].brandBrandId.brandId)//ERROR HERE!
```

**Error**
TypeError: Cannot read property 'brandId' of undefined

## Question

How can I search models under the brand 2 with JavaScript? Like give me every model which has `brandId=2`. I was trying to for loop it, but I really can't do it and I hope that there is some better and wiser way to do it. I need every `modelId` and `modelName` under the specific brand. THANKS!

**Solution**

```
function getModels() {
                    var brandsmodels=new Array();
                     for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {

                        if (models[i].brandBrandId.brandId === selectedBrand) {
                            brandsmodels.push({
                                "modelId": ""+models[i].modelId,
                                "modelName": ""+models[i].modelName,
                                "brandId": ""+selectedBrand
                            });

                        }
                    }
                    $scope.brandsmodels=brandsmodels;

                }
```

Comment: Your title says DOM, but in Your question there is nothing related to DOM.

Comment: *"I hope that there is some better and wiser way to do it."* Not really. Please post what you tried. A loop is not *that* complicated. Maybe this helps: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196).

Comment: It is also tagged "arrays" and "for-loop", but those are not present either.

Comment: Please, let us show the code you already tried!

Comment: @user4759923: This is *not* JSON.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :) I was trying to read answers and somehow my brains was still thinking DOM :) JSON I meant.

Comment: @Sami: This is not JSON.

Comment: @Felix Kling: This is everything what my REST service is giving to me. @Produces({ "application/json"})
    public List<Model> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

Comment: Still, what you posted is not JSON. Even if you got the data as JSON, the issue is with accessing the parsed data, not with JSON. Also, what exactly do you expect `[i].brandBrandId` to do?

Comment: @Felix Kling: I just want to see is my syntax working or not. If I check my "JSON" with developer tool, that is the syntax what it's showing to me. For instance [0].brandBrandId.brandId,[1].brandBrandId.brandId and [2].brandBrandId.brandId

Comment: `[i]` creates an array with a single element, the value of `i`. If you want to access the ith element of `models`, then you have to write `models[i]`, and then `models[i].brandBrandId.brandId` will work as well. Even if you are not very familiar with JS, this is how it works in many languages.  [Learn more about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: console.log(i+" : " +models[i].brandBrandId.brandId)--->TypeError: Cannot read property 'brandId' of undefined

Comment: Then the array seems to have an object/value that does not have a `brandBrandId` property. Not much we can do about it.

Comment: @Felix Kling : I have no idea why it didn't work at first, but it did work later. Please check my solution part of my edited question. I hate javascript a lot :) Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter array method:

```
input.filter(function(model) {
   return model.brandBrandId.brandId == 2;
});
```

Comment: I tried this: function getModels() {
                        console.log("getModels()---->");
                        $scope.models = modelService.query();
                        models.filter(function(model) {
                            return model.brandBrandId.brandId === 2;
                        });//TypeError: Cannot read property 'brandId' of undefined